# marking nearby places with google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Hell Friends,
I am trying to generate google map which shows nearby places such as schools, banks, bustops, atms, etc based location of address entered by user or available at website. I found one website has this exact feature at below link:

http://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/3-BHK-1800-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Rent-Trimulgherry-in-Hyderabad&id=TBnBPt2P60ZzpSvf+uAgZw==

you can see under location heading it shows all importante information with in radius. Can some one help me how to do this kind map for me please . I am not a programmer or technical specialist.
THanks

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) .

The `Google Places API` is a service that returns information about Places — defined within this API as `establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest` — using `HTTP requests`. Place requests specify locations as `latitude/longitude coordinates`.

For example, `Place Details` requests return more detailed information about a specific Place as your wish.

Note that, The `id and referenc`e fields are `deprecated` as of June 24, 2014. They are replaced by the new `place ID`, a unique identifier that can be `used to compare places and to retrieve information about a place`.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).